# change the font weight of date cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid table with this colmodel:

```
 { name: 'Readfl', formatter: GetImages, align: "center", width: "25", sortable: true,    "resizable": true, search: true, edit: true },
{ name: 'Datim', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { 'srcformat': 'Y-m-d', 'newformat': 'd.m.Y' }, width: "60", align: "center", hidden: false, "resizable": true, search: true }
```

if 'Readfl' is true i want to set bold font-weight for 'Datim'.
The problem is that i already use 'formatter' for 'Datim' and i can't use a second formatter to return bold text for the 'Datim'. Is there any why to use a second formatter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS class to these `Datim` cells:

```
{ 
  name: 'Datim',
  formatter: 'date',
  ...
  classes: "datim" 
}
```

And then in a CSS file or in your html `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .datim { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
```

Comment: but i want to set the bold font-weight only if Readfl is true, if not than no bold

Comment: @user576914 you'll have to use javascript then. Attach an event handler for when the value of Readfl changes, then add or remove the css class programatically.